# use multiple value in a single cell to do vlookup in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple values in a single cell(ex:a,b,c,d,e). Then I want to use vlookup to find the corresponding values(ex: 11,22,33,44,55) and save the values in another single cells. How to achieve it by using VBA?

Comment: Are you required to keep those that data in a single cell? What have you tried? There are a few ways off the top of my head with and without VBA. With VBA, I would suggest putting that cell into a `String`, then splitting that with a delimiter, and using a dictionary perhaps to replace the data. Or, you could split that data up in the spreadsheet (or variables inside VBA), and running Vlookup on that.  But again, what have you tried so far? What's working/not working?

Comment: VBA has a split function that would come in handy here, but maybe you already know that? If you paste what code you already have we can judge where you need help and point you in the right direction

Comment: Why store multiple values in a single cell? Or do you actually mean you have multiple values *each one of which* is in a single cell?